# Mock a static method with generic return type

Tags: static, mocking, powermock

Static method:

```
public static List<? extends Object> convert(String destClassName, List<? extends Object> srcList) {
    List<Object> destList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX..........

    return destList;
}
```

Mock:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(ReflectionUtil.class);
```

Error: I cannot use `when().thenReturn()` to mock this method

This is the error:

> The method thenReturn(List) in the type
>   OngoingStubbing> is not applicable
>   for the arguments (List)

```
when(ReflectionUtil.convert(any(String.class),Matchers.<List<? extends Object>>any())).thenReturn(fundList);
```

This method was created by my colleague, and it has passed UAT test, so I cannot change the method.
Is there any graceful approach to fix this question?

Comment: Please give a full [mcve] !

Comment: I fix this issue.But I don't know why.
original:List<? extends Object> fundList  =  new ArrayList();
fixed :List fundList  =  new ArrayList();
just remove the type.